# Does SSL Certificate protects the "network" or "just" the data?

Tags: security, ssl, iis, server

If I use a SSL certificate for an API deployed to my own IIS server, it will protect my network, my ports, or only the data of the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply SSL certificate and https for your web api in IIS. SSL handshake will be applied before the connection. So it will create a security channel to enhance the connection and avoid man-in-the-middle attack. At the same time, all the data are transmitted under encryption. So hacker won't be able to see th clear context because they don't have key to decrypt the information.

In a word, SSL secure connection and data not network. IIS client certificate can also be used to authenticate user identity.

Answer (score 1):

SSL/TLS certificates are a means of authentication. The certificat authority where you register your certificate (e.g. LetsEncrypt) will vouch that you indeed own the domain you are trying to register a certifiate for. These certificates are then used to bootstrap an encrypted TLS connection between the users of your server and your server. Subsequent data transfer is then encrypted (I assume this is what you meant by 'protected'?).

I am not sure what you mean by 'protecting' your network or port. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: What I mean by "protect" is "have any action" under the network, the computer that is used to host the Web Server or only on the on the data transfered between the Web Server.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is digital certificate provide authentication/authorization for a webapp/website for data and help to share information or "data" in Internet encrypted.

If you want protect a network, DMZ or demilitarized zone implementation helps you in Internet world.